# Area51 Badge Request: Jack of All Trades

Tags: feature-request, area-51, badge-request

Ok, so when you get +200 rep that account is shown under your A51 account card to show what you have "achieved". What I am proposing is that a badge is made for if you have enough, maybe 5, accounts that have +200 rep you get a badge called Jack Of All Trades.

Your thoughts on this matter? Suggestions? Tweaks to what I am proposing?

Comment: Is it asking too much that questions relating to area51 be tagged as such by the questioner?

Comment: @Neil, you really don't want to see any area51 stuff do ya?

Comment: @Justin Correctomundo! And I get  a bit ticked off about having to keep adding the tags - it's like those people on SO that can't be bothered to say what programming language they are using. Grrr.

Comment: @Neil: Sorry, I'll put the Area511 next time I have a question like this.

Answer (score 2):

I like this, it made me chuckle.  But I don't see what purpose it serves beyond providing people with that initial chuckle.  Badges are designed to reward good behaviors, or occasionally to throw a bone to some unlucky user — lookin' at you, [Tumbleweed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/38/tumbleweed).

If you reach the proposed criteria, you already get to show off by having more little icons in your A51 flair, and with the rep itself on the individual sites.  There aren't any badges for reaching n rep on a given site because rep is already immediately visible to begin with, and people need no additional incentive to try to increase it.